# How to save the generated csv file by my plugin in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, csv

I am creating a plugin that will generate a CSV file of users, I want to save the generated csv file with unique name.

**My current code:-**

```
$output_filename = 'members-' . date('F j, Y') . '.csv';
    $output_handle = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' ); 
    header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
    header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
    header( 'Content-type: text/csv' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $output_filename );
    header( 'Expires: 0' );
    header( 'Pragma: public' );
    fputcsv( $output_handle, $header_row );
    foreach ( $data_rows as $data_row ) {
      fputcsv( $output_handle, $data_row );
    }
    fclose( $output_handle );
    die();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to make this file downloadable from the browser?

If yes, try with this headers :

```
$output_filename = 'members-' . date('F j, Y') . '.csv';

// Disable caching
$now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

// Force download  
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");

// Encoding on response body
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

fputcsv( $output_handle, $header_row );
foreach ( $data_rows as $data_row ) {
  fputcsv( $output_handle, $data_row );
}
fclose( $output_handle );
die();
```

Comment: I want to save it in WordPress directory so that I can send email with the attachment. Another question - is it possible to send the generated CSV as attachment in email without saving it in directory?